# How can I create singleton instance of an dependency class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am bit new to patterns and using them.

I want to configure an object of a dependency class(say A.) once and use it through out my app. I tried making a singleton wrapper class on top of it, but failed miserably. I tried something like:

```
 public class B {
  public static A a = new A();
  public static A getInstance() {
      return a;
  }

  private B() {
    a.configure(); 
  }
 }
```

I think calling `B.getInstance()` won't configure the object here. What I want here is to configure A's instance once and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your singleton class is B right ? in your sample code you use the singleton pattern for the inner A, which doesnt make much sense.

From my understanding you should go for something like that :

```
public class B {
    private static B _instance;
    public static B getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new B(new A());
        }
        return _instance;
    }

   private A _a;

   private B (A a) {
       _a = a;
       _a.configure();
   }
}
```

Comment: But this doesnt give me instance of A right? I want to configure class A and get its instance. My bad if i wasnt too clear in my question.

Comment: then add a method in B like getA() { return _a; }

Comment: ok so this seems to be working... thanks @Ash, hope this is useful to others.
public class B {
    private static B _instance;
    private static A a = new A();
    private static void init() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new B(a);
        }
    }

    public static A getInstance() {
     _instance.init();
     return a;
    }
   private B (A a) {
       _a = a;
       _a.configure();
   }
}